# Liblog adapter for wix custom action

Tags: wix, custom-action, serilog, liblog

Currently I am logging Wix Custom Action log messages to a file using `Session.Log()`. My application uses `Liblog` with `Serilog` for logging.

Is there a way to have an adapter class for `Liblog` that writes log messages to Custom Action `Session`?

The reason for trying to write installer log messages using `Liblog` is that dependent libraries of Custom Action assembly writes several log messages to `Liblog` and I do not want to have two different log files for installer.